# Hacer que div desplegable haga su función pero horizontalmente

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hola tengo este script el cual funciona muy bien, pero ¿Cómo haría para que su función la haga horizontalmente? me refiero que no se esconda de abajo para arriba si no que se esconda de derecha a izquierda.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button8" name="nueva_cabana"  id="nueva_cabana" value="Mostrar"/>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
//$('#anadir_cabana').hide();
$("#nueva_cabana").val('Ocultar');
$("#nueva_cabana").on("click", function(e) {
  var $boton = $(this);
  $('#anadir_cabana').toggle(500, function() {
    $boton.val($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Ocultar' : 'Mostrar');
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
});
</script>
<div id="anadir_cabana">ESTE ES EL CONTENIDO!!!</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Te sugiero que uses `.animate()` y que uses un contenedor para envolver el contenido.  Se veria algo asi:

```css
#anadir_cabana {
  width:200px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#text{
 width:200px;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="button" class="button8" name="nueva_cabana" id="nueva_cabana" value="Mostrar"/>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    //$('#anadir_cabana').hide();
    $("#nueva_cabana").val('Ocultar');
    $("#nueva_cabana").on("click", function(e) {
      var $boton = $(this);
      $('#anadir_cabana').animate({width: [ "toggle", "swing" ]}, 500, function() {
        $boton.val($(this).is(':visible') ? 'Ocultar' : 'Mostrar');
      });
      e.preventDefault();
    });
  });
</script>
<div id="anadir_cabana"><div id="text">ESTE ES EL CONTENIDO!!!</div></div>
```

Comment: Muy bien amigo me sirvio, como haria para que se oculte al contrario de izquierda a derecha